# Исходный код для ключевых слов async/await C#

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-faq

Допустим есть `int` - ключевое слово для `System.Int32`. Есть `string` - ключевое слово для `System.String`. А есть `async` и `await`, это ключевые слова для каких классов? Пытался искать в [microsoft reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/), но там нашел только [private bool async](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Cache/IERequestCache.cs,8d2ab18bc34e108f,references)

Comment: Это просто ключевые слова, как `return` или `for`. Это не классы.

Comment: @aepot понятно, спасибо)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Для .NET 5/6 вместо Reference Source (он содержит устаревший код .NET Framework 4.8) используйте лучше Github - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime или вот такой сайт еще есть https://source.dot.net.*

Если хочется узнать, что же на самом деле такое `async`, то можно открыть https://sharplab.io и выбрать C# в дропдауне Results

Там такой код слева

```cs
public void M() {
}
```

И если его изменить на

```cs
public async void M() {
}
```

То справа получится вот такая конструкция

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <M>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncVoidMethodBuilder <>t__builder;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult();
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}

[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<M>d__0))]
public void M()
{
    <M>d__0 stateMachine = default(<M>d__0);
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
}
```

Вот она, асинхронная машина состояний.

Теперь `await`.

```cs
public async void M() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Он добавляет поле и изменяет метод `MoveNext()`

```cs
private TaskAwaiter <>u__1;

private void MoveNext()
{
    int num = <>1__state;
    try
    {
        TaskAwaiter awaiter;
        if (num != 0)
        {
            awaiter = Task.Delay(1000).GetAwaiter();
            if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
            {
                num = (<>1__state = 0);
                <>u__1 = awaiter;
                <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref this);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            awaiter = <>u__1;
            <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter);
            num = (<>1__state = -1);
        }
        awaiter.GetResult();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
        return;
    }
    <>1__state = -2;
    <>t__builder.SetResult();
}
```

Вот так на самом деле выглядит `await`.

Как видно, эти 2 ключевых слова хоть и являются "ненастоящими", а преобразуются в другой код, но они совсем не похожи на классы.

---

Если понравилась методика исследования, то изучите во что превращается реализация итератора `IEnumerable<T>` с `yield return`. Там тоже интересно.

Comment: Спасибо! Отличный ответ, причём без происходящего иногда отсыла "читай документацию!" - хотя и это, без сомнения, было бы полезно

Comment: А что это за приписки `<>` в коде?

Comment: @AlAvenger считайте это как просто символы, их использует компилятор, чтобы давать имена переменным и классам, и не конфликтовать с переменными, написанными вами в коде. Вы сами такие символы в C# использовать не сможете, их может использовать только компилятор. Грубо говоря, если они вас смущают при чтении кода, то их можно просто убрать, и ничего не сломается.